# Math Library in C & Exersices

Tags: c, math

I tried to find a good place to ask my question, which isn't programming, though it implies programming in C.

Our schoolteachers told us that we need to start exercise our programing skills, in C, based on math exersices. Even if I search the web for the best ways to solve such exersices and I came up with the Math library [`<math.h>`] I couldn't find a good page with many examples of solving exersices. My best course so far is Wikipedia but I can understand the fact that the Wikipedia can't store all the functionalities the library gives. I even looked in some examples  want to find a complete coursebook for sovling all good math exersices we can make with a paper and a pen!

Have anyone any good idea?

Comment: The de facto reference: http://www.nr.com/

Answer (score 3):

So, you are trying to learn programming to solve math problems, that's good. But, I think you are getting a wrong idea about programming, Programming does not solve problems for you. To solve a problem, you have to decide on an algorithm to solve a problem and then create programmatic statements, in whichever language you like, then the program that you have created will give you an outcome based on the algorithm. You have to take the outcome and then decide yourself for further study.

**for example**

finding a factorial of a number

```
int i = number;
fact = 1;
while(i > 0)
fact * = i;
```

this way you will get a factorial of the number you specify, It is you who has to decide whether your algorithm is working fine, by comparing it with manual work, or with records. As you can see, the above program is an infinite loop and it is me who has to debug such issues, the program does not do that. Then What does a program do, it just automates what you do manual and help you save time and improve efficiency at work.

So to solve exercises, you have to understand problem statements and then script a program. I see you are talking about `math library`, we have good resource online to study important math functions which are highly useful, for in depth understand of their working open up the library files and study.

**A Program can never solve your problem without you writing it, and deciding on its efficiency**

Answer (score 0):

See if this [cmath](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/) solves you problem.

> Header `<cmath>` declares a set of functions to compute common mathematical operations and transformations

Comment: good for first look but not very instractable! My question is specific